# are these two optimization problems involving matrices equivalent?

Tags: matrices, optimization

Assume you have matrices  **F, W*, P*** and we have the following optimization problem over matrix **P**

$$ \bf{ min (|W^* F P^* | - |W^* FP |})$$

can we say the above problem is similar to

$$\bf{min |P^*|-|P|}$$

If no, then how can i simplify the first problem? thank you

Comment: What norm is that?

Comment: This is the determinant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming $W^*FP^*$ , $W^*FP$, $P^*$, and $P$ are all squares since we are talking about determinants. Suppose $P$ and $P^*$ are both in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then $W^*F \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as well.

Then we have $$|W^*FP^*|-|W^*FP|=|W^*F|(|P^*|-|P|)$$

It is possible that $|W^*F|$ is non-positive, hence the question need not be equivalent. It is equivalent when $|W^*F|>0$.